# How to add only all dot files and directories to a git repo?

Tags: git

How to add only all dot files to a git repo?
I tried:

```
$ gitc add .*
fatal: ..: '..' is outside repository
```

Also, how to add only all dot directories recursively in git, except for .mozilla?

Comment: What do you mean by recursively? Do these folder contain any files?

Comment: Have you considered using a .gitignore?

Comment: @evolutionxbox:
Yes, the folders contain files and more folders.

Comment: @Ryan Millares:
Good idea.  I will try .gitginore.

Comment: What is `gitc`?

Comment: @Schwern: gitc is alias:
$ alias gitc='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$home0/config_repo --work-tree=$home0'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is best handled with a .gitignore, then you can safely use `git add .`.

It can be simplest to write it inside out: ignore everything, then unignore selectively.

```
/*/
!/.*/
!.gitignore
/.mozilla/
```

1. Ignore everything at the top level.
2. Unignore top level directories which start with a dot.
3. Unignore any .gitignore files.
4. Unignore a top level .mozilla directory.

Here's a test directory.

```
.
├── .gitignore
├── .mozilla
│   └── no
├── .no
├── .yes
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── .mozilla
│   ├── .yes
│   └── yes
└── no
```

And here is what `git add .` sees.

```
    new file:   .gitignore
    new file:   .yes/.gitignore
    new file:   .yes/.mozilla
    new file:   .yes/.yes
    new file:   .yes/yes
```